# building emacs in a docker container

Tags: build, docker

Until very recently, I've been able to build emacs from source in a docker container using [this recipe](https://github.com/ensime/ensime-docker/blob/v1.x/Dockerfile). However as of last week, all my builds have been failing with

```
Warning: Your system has a gap between BSS and the
heap (32188607 bytes).  This usually means that exec-shield
or something similar is in effect.  The dump may
fail because of this.  See the section about
exec-shield in etc/PROBLEMS for more information.
```

I've read the `etc/PROBLEMS` and it doesn't make any sense to me. Does anybody know how to interpret this for a docker container and what I can do to get emacs building again on `hub.docker.com`?

I've tried

```
cat 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/exec-shield
```

but I don't think that is really the problem, it doesn't exist in the container.

- cross-posted to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544423
- upstream bug report https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22801

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is also being answered here (since you already found my github bug report):

https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=23529

For the moment, and likely it will be this way until the emacs build system changes, the only valid solutions are:

- Don't build with a Dockerfile and build in a running container that has a seccomp profile that allows the personality syscall. For example:

  `docker run --rm -it --security-opt seccomp=unconfined emacs-builder-image`
- Disable /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space before building:

  `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space; docker build .`

I maintain docker images at https://hub.docker.com/r/silex/emacs

Comment: Are you sure we need a build system change? I thought the current build system already handled it.

Comment: Emacs 27 will not need this anymore because of the pdumper work that was done.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable dumping with `env CANNOT_DUMP=yes ./configure`.  Does this not work on Docker?

Comment: It "works" but then you can only run emacs in batch mode, which is not very useful... might be sufficient for specific cases tho.